Bezier Curves Reverting to Constant Interpolation When Using Cyclic Extrapolation in Graph Editor
I'm experiencing an issue in Blender's Graph Editor where my keyframes are set to Bezier interpolation, but when I enable cyclic extrapolation, the curves switch to constant interpolation instead of continuing the smooth Bezier pattern.
How can I fix this so that the curves extrapolate correctly without changing to constant interpolation?
Without cyclic modifier:

Witch cyclic modifier:

Thanks
